# Does yoga cause as many injuries as other sports?

Tags: healthcare, yoga

This [Telegraph article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/06/28/yogamore-dangerous-previously-thought-scientists-say/) claims:

> Yoga is more dangerous than previously thought and causes as many injuries as other sports, a study has found.
>
> [...] in a recent study yoga caused musculoskeletal pain - mostly in the
> arms
>
> [...]
>
> Professor Evangelos Pappas, of Sydney University, the study's lead researcher said: "Yoga may be a bit more dangerous than previously thought.
>
> "Our study found the incidence of pain caused by yoga is more than 10 percent per year - which is comparable to the rate of all sports injuries combined among the physically active population.

Is the practice of yoga as susceptible to injuries as sports?

Comment: Related question: [Has yoga been shown to have a healing effect?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1770/has-yoga-been-shown-to-have-a-healing-effect) Yoga seems to encompass a pretty broad variety of activities, which might make it hard to give a clear answer to a question like the one in the title of this post.

Comment: The related question talks about a psychological healing but I'm referring to a physical damage. Psychological healings are hard to prove or disprove.